# Is this a scoring error?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, score

[cletus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082005/2121592#2121592) has 2 votes up + correct answer = 35 points

However looking at [his scoring graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) it says he got 170 points for that answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the yellow glow around the "accepted answer" tick. It means that this was a bounty question. Move the cursor over the tick; the tooltip will show additional details (bounty amount and accepting date).

Comment: oh sweet, thanks for the explanation :)